# Collection (as opposed to member) endpoint in Grails REST?

Tags: rest, grails, routes, grails-2.0

In rails there's an easy way to add a collection end point to routes. e.g.

```
resources :books do
  member do
    get 'publisher'    # /books/id/publisher
  end

  collection do
    get 'total_count'  # /books/total_count
  end
end
```

Is there a similar way to map the `total_count` endpoint in Grails? The example here ( http://grails.org/doc/2.3.1/guide/single.html#urlMappings ) only shows a member route.

```
"/books"(resources: "book") {
    "/publisher"(controller:"publisher")
    "/total_count"(controller: "publisher") // ??? can this work?
}
```

I am currently using Grails 2.3.4.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

It was simpler than I thought though if there's a more canonical way of solving this I'd appreciate the feedback.

Basically I defined the collection endpoint before the resource endpoint.

```
class UrlMappings {
    static mappings = {
        "/books/total_count" (controller: "Book", action: "totalCount", method: "GET")
        "/books" (resources: "Book")
    }
}
```

So far it appears to be working.